# Is there a way to rename automatically generated routes JSON file in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a problem, when I click to go to the `/analytics` page on my site, adblockers block the `analytics.json` file that's being requested by Next.js as they think it's an analytics tracker (it's not, it's a page listing analytics products).

Is there a way to rename the route files Next.js uses when navigating to server-side rendered pages on the client-side?

I want to either obfuscate the names so they're not machine readable, or have a way to rename them all.

Any help appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[With thanks to @gaston-flores](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/39923#discussioncomment-3470393) I've managed to get something working.

In my instance `/analytics` is a dynamic page for a category, so I moved my `pages/[category]/index.tsx` file to `pages/[category]/category.tsx` and added the following rewrite:

```js
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/:category",
        destination: "/:category/category",
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

This now gets the `category.json` file rather than `analytics.json`, which passes the adblockers checks and renders as expected.

Note that due to having a dynamic file name in the `pages/[category]` directory (`pages/[category]/[product].tsx`), I had to move that to `pages/[category]/product/[product].tsx` as I was seeing the `/analytics` page redirected to `/analytics/category` for some reason without this tweak.

[image: network tab showing category.json?category=analytics being fetched]